# Cannot specify a custom configuration file for Grafana

Tags: grafana

I've seen so many questions on stack for this issue, but none of them seem to be answered accurately

1. I have downloaded and extracted the Grafana binary archive to location `/A`
2. I want to run it with a configuration file located at `/B/config.ini`

I always receive this error:

> Grafana-server Init Failed: Could not find config defaults, make sure
> homepath command line parameter is set or working directory is
> homepath

When running this command:

```
/A/bin/grafana-server -config /B/config.ini web
```

Questions :/

1. Can you not run Grafana with a configuration file outside the
   homepath?
2. What is the homepath for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what fixed it, but one thing to check is

- There are paths inside the config file, make sure they point to valid locations, especially if they are relative to the working directory

I eventually got this command to work once all the paths in the config were valid

```
/A/bin/grafana-server --config /B/config.ini web
```